# Como transformar a saída de um comando numa variável no CMD?

Tags: cmd

Olá, desde que comecei a pesquisar sobre esses comandos do **CMD**, essa dúvida sobre  como transformar a saída de um comando numa variável tem sido a que mais me tomou tempo.

Eu vi muitos códigos por aí, muitos citavam que o comando **FOR** poderia ser usado nisso,  mas eu não sei usar esse comando ainda, não entendi a lógica dele e inclusive se alguém pudesse me explicar isso, agradeceria muito.

Bom, o código com o qual consegui redirecionar a saída de um comando para uma variável.

`mountvol %SystemDrive% /l >0 && set /p abc=<0`

Com esse comando eu enfim consegui redirecionar a saída de **Mountvol** direto para uma  variável, aliás direto não, acredito que os dados **STDOUT** foram primeiro direcionados  para **STDIN** (com o **>0** ) e depois sim foram usados para definir a variável. Eu não  tenho certeza disso porque apesar de eu ter ficado dois dias para chegar nesse código,  algumas regras desses comandos ainda estão obscuras pra mim.

Por exemplo, por tudo o que li sobre os redirecionadores e identificadores, eu não deveria ter que colocar o  **0** (zero) depois do redirecionador de entrada ( **<** ), mesmo assim se não usá-lo o comando não funciona.

Além disso existe uma limitação nesse código que eu queria ser capaz de contornar, a limitação está  nas quebras de linha que várias saídas de comando tem. Parece não ser possível definir valores de variáveis com quebras de linha, alguém poderia ajudar nessa limitação?

Por exemplo, a saída do comando abaixo que teria uma quebra de linha logo no começo, não  poderia ser setada como o valor da variável `%abc%`.

`reg query HKLM >0 && set /p abc=<0`

Somente as saídas que não tivessem nenhuma quebra de linha poderiam ser totalmente  setadas como o valor de uma variável, eu acho que dá pra contornar isso com algum comando que altere a  formatação do texto.

alguém pode ajudar a melhorar isso?

**Atualização**

Para informação estou usando um arquivo **.BAT**.

Fiz essa postagem porque acredito que transformar a saída de um comando numa variável é  uma boa forma de guardar as informações obtidas desse comando. Uma vez que a informação  se tornou uma variável, é possível consultá-la, usá-la em conjunto com outro comando,  alterá-la e muito mais.

Abaixo está um *pedaço* do que estou fazendo aqui, dá pra ver que redirecionei os dados  de saída de `mountvol` para a variável `%guid%`, depois ajustei esses dados para definir  o parâmetro de outro comando. Isso habilita a **Proteção do Sistema** na partição onde o  sistema online está instalado, não execute isso a não ser que entenda que esses dados  irão apagar os que já definem suas configurações atuais. Nesse caso os códigos são para  um **.BAT**.

```
@echo off
::
set chv=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SPP\Clients
set vlr={09F7EDC5-294E-4180-AF6A-FB0E6A0E9513}
set tip=REG_MULTI_SZ
::
mountvol %SystemDrive% /l >0 && set /p guid=<0
::
reg add "%chv%" /v "%vlr%" /t %tip% /d "%guid: =%:(%SystemDrive:~,1%%%3A)" /f && cls && echo    Comando executado com sucesso! && goto fim
::
cls
echo    Houve algum erro, execute novamente como Administrador.
::
:fim
pause>nul
exit
```

Eu consigo então transformar a primeira linha de uma saída numa variável (caso exista) e  modificar os caracteres dela usando o deslocamento (**~**) ou atribuição (**=**), como é  possível ver acima, mas o ideal seria poder modificar os caracteres de toda a saída e não  apenas os da primeira linha.

**Correção**

Me enganei pessoal, não sou capaz de redirecionar os dados de **STDOUT** para **STDIN**  como mencionei antes, isso é impossível pra mim ainda, o que eu estava fazendo era  redirecionar **STDOUT** para um arquivo sem extensão nomeado **0** (zero) que era criado  dentro da pasta **System32** (diretório do **CMD**).
Acontece que por erro de interpretação meu sobre o que li **[aqui](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc772622(v=ws.10).aspx)**,  eu  pensei mesmo que estava redirecionando para **STDIN**, que é representado por um zero,  mas valeu a informação.
Você pode testar e confirmar isso, digite o comando que segue no prompt e verá que na  verdade os dados **STDOUT** do primeiro comando são passados para o arquivo **02825** que  será criado em **System32**, se o primeiro comando for executado corretamente o arquivo  **02825** será aberto pelo Bloco de Notas, mostrando a saída **STDOUT** do primeiro  comando.

```
reg query HKLM >02825 && notepad 02825
```

Você pode ver o arquivo **02825** pelo Explorer com o comando  `Explorer /select,02825` e  para excluí-lo pode usar `del 02825`.
Nenhuma novidade então, a não ser que agora sabemos que não precisamos gravar a saída num  arquivo com extensão exatamente, como um **.txt**.

Comment: O prompt de comando do Windows é bastante limitado em relação ao **Windows PowerShell**. Você já procurou saber se consegue fazer o que precisa usando o PowerShell? http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/Library/bb978526.aspx

Comment: Já ouvi falar desse **PowerShell** mas nunca usei ele, por enquanto estou tentando no **CMD** véio de guerra mesmo... como mencionei nem sei comandos básicos como o **FOR** ainda, estou engatinhando nisso.

Comment: Já que está apenas começando, comece pelo melhor ;-)

Comment: Estendi um pouco meu comentário em uma resposta. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 7):

Uma opção é usar o [Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/Library/bb978526.aspx), que pode ser visto como um prompt de comando do Windows (cmd) mais moderno e poderoso (embora seja ainda mais que isso).

### Exemplo

Para setar em uma variável a saída do comando `mountvol`, passando parâmetros para este comando (no caso, eu passei o parâmetro `/?`):

```
PS C:\Users\caffé> $mountVolHelp = mountvol /?
```

Agora, para ver o conteúdo da variável `$mountVolHelp`, com todo o texto inclusive quebras de linha, basta digitar seu nome:

```
PS C:\Users\caffé> $mountVolHelp
Cria, exclui ou lista um ponto de montagem de volume.

MOUNTVOL [unidade:]caminho NomeVolume
MOUNTVOL [unidade:]caminho /D
MOUNTVOL [unidade:]caminho /L
MOUNTVOL [unidade:]caminho /P
                            ...
    caminho     Especifica a pasta NTFS existente onde residirá o ponto de
                montagem.
    NomeVolume  Especifica o nome de volume que é o destino do ponto de
                montagem.
    /D          Remove o ponto de montagem do volume da pasta especificada.
    /L          Lista o nome do volume montado para a pasta especificada.
                            ...
    /R          Remove pastas e configurações do Registro de pontos de
                montagem de volume que não estão mais no sistema.
    /N          Desativa a montagem automática de novos volumes.
    /E          Reativa a montagem automática de novos volumes.
                            ...
```

### Um exemplo de loop no PowerShell

O código abaixo imprime o conteúdo de `$mountVolHelp` adicionando o texto "Rá! " no começo de cada linha:

```
foreach ($linha in $mountvolHelp) {"Rá! " + $linha}
```

Assim como no *for each* de várias linguagens de programação, no código acima a variável `$linha` é criada dentro do próprio loop e a cada iteração recebe o valor de uma linha da variável `$mountvolHelp`, que neste contexto é tratada como uma lista de linhas.

### Outro exemplo de uso do *for each*

```
PS C:\Users\caffé> foreach ($numero in 1,2,3) {$numero}
1
2
3
```

No exemplo acima, "1,2,3" foi tratado pelo *for each* como uma lista de números.

### Exemplo de leitura no PowerShell das variáveis de ambiente do Windows

Para ler %UserProfile%, por exemplo, uma das maneiras é:

```
PS C:\Users\caffé> $env:UserProfile
C:\Users\caffé
```

A segunda linha do código acima é saída do comando. Para atribuir o valor desta variável de ambiente a uma outra variável no PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\caffé> $UserProfile = $env:UserProfile
```

Agora a variável `$UserProfile` contém "*C:\Users\caffé*".

### Conclusão

Com o Windows PowerShell você pode fazer tudo que faz com o "cmd", só que mais fácil, com mais recursos e contando com mais documentação.

Para abrir o Windows Powersheel, apenas pressione a tecla "windows" e digite "powershell", será mostrado um atalho para o "Windows PowerShell", que à primeira vista se parece muito com o "cmd". Outra opção é digitar "powershell" no próprio "cmd". Imediatamente aparecerá um "PS" no começo da linha do prompt de comando, indicando que você agora está no PowerShell.

Comment: Eu estou olhando pra isso agora, eu defini **$abc=reg query HKLM** e esse **$abc** já recebeu toda a saída do comando reg query sem esforço, muito interessante, depois eu usei o redirecionador ( **>** ) e mandei para um arquivo de texto como no CMD, a diferença é que essa variável do **PowerShell** realmente pode receber várias linhas, muito bom. Vou continuar fuçando aqui... notei que as variáveis como **%SystemDrive%** ou **%UserProfile%** não funcionam nele, como posso obter esses caminhos ? Tentei **$SystemDrive$** e outras mas ainda não consegui, de qualquer forma muito obrigado por isso.

Comment: @UnanTec Fico feliz que você esteja animado com este recurso. Realmente é outro universo em relação ao cmd. Atualizei minha resposta com um exemplo de como ler variáveis de ambiente do Windows.

Comment: +1 por recomendar o powershell.

Answer (score 5):

Duas maneiras simples:

```
aplicacaoOuComando arg0 arg1 > temp.txt
set /p VAR=<temp.txt
```

outra:

```
for /f %%i in ('aplicacaoOuComando arg0 arg1') do set VAR=%%i
```

**EDIÇÃO**

O comando `for /f` é um parse de arquivos. Teoricamente falando, se você passa um comando, ele manda o **STDOUT** para o input deste parse.

Comment: Somente complementando, mesmo que a saída tenha quebras de linha, desta forma deve ser possível pegar o texto todo e colocar na variável. Não sei se você está usando ela numa aplicação ou em comandos exclusivamente batch.

Comment: Esse código **set /p VAR=<temp.txt** sofre da mesma limitação que o código que eu usei, a diferença é que esse cria um arquivo no disco enquanto o meu código redireciona a saída do comando ( **STDOUT** ) para a entrada ( **STDIN** ).Já o comando **FOR** que você usou eu não entendo justamente porque nunca li uma explicação clara sobre esse comando, eu fico tentando entender o que raio é esse **/f** ou esse **in** ou ainda aquele tal de **delims=** que também aparece de vez em quando. Nunca li uma explicação clara sobre esse comando por isso ainda não entendi como ele funciona. Obrigado.

Comment: @UnanTec Adicionei também um exemplo de **FOR** para PowerShell. Vou parar senão isso vira um tutorial.

Comment: @UnanTec desculpe perguntar, mas qual linguagem você está invocando este comando? Será que não existe uma outra maneira de pegar o output sem ser setar uma variável e depois pegar o resultado dela?

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Consegui em arquivo BAT! Este fórum foi muito útil, obrigado aos participantes.

Com base nas informações deste fórum, consegui fazer uma pequena sequência de comandos que salva a primeira linha da saída de um comando em uma variável. Ficou assim:

```
"COMANDO QUE TENHA SAÍDA" > VARtemp.txt
set /p SuaVariavel=<VARtemp.txt
DEL VARtemp.txt
```

Dependendo do seu comando a saída pode conter várias linhas, tabulações e caracteres. Esse método vai gravar em **"SuaVariavel"** apenas a primeira linha, que dependendo pode estar vazia, sem informações.

Caso necessite pode ser feito a edição do conteúdo do arquivo **"VARtemp.txt"** através de comandos como o **FIND** para que possa ficar apenas com o conteúdo que deseja.

Abra o Arquivo de saída **"VARtemp.txt"** e analise seu conteúdo para estudar o método mais eficaz para edição dele através de comandos e extrair apenas o conteúdo que deseja para sua variável.

No meu caso, eu necessitava apenas saber se existia determinado caractere em minha saída para o arquivo **VARtemp.txt**. Utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
"COMANDO QUE TENHA SAÍDA" > VARtemp.txt

FIND /i "CARACTERE" "VARtemp.txt"
if NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ( 
  set /p SuaVariavel= "EXISTE O CARACTERE"
  DEL "VARtemp.txt"
  GOTO INICIO
)
set /p SuaVariavel= "NÃO EXISTE O CARACTERE"

:INICIO
REM ### Continuação do script BAT ###
```

Boa sorte e bom trabalho.

Att

Thiago Morais

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção para **salvar a variável do comando via looping**  <kbd>**`for`**</kbd> :

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::
set "chv=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SPP\Clients"
set "vlr={09F7EDC5-294E-4180-AF6A-FB0E6A0E9513}
set "tip=REG_MULTI_SZ"
::
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('mountvol %%SystemDrive%% /l') do set "guid=%%i"
:: 
rem :: use echo/ para verificar o seu comando com as variaveis:
echo/reg add "!chv!" /f /v "!vlr!" /t !tip! /d "!guid!:%SystemDrive:~,1%%%3A" && goto :zOk: || goto :nOk:

:zOk:
echo/    Comando executado com sucesso^^! & goto :eof

:nOk:
echo/    Houve algum erro, execute novamente como Administrador.^^! & timeout /t -1 >nul & goto :eof
```

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente o set esta mudando a variavel
O comando && tem a regra de quebra de linha para chama outro comando.

Espero ter ajudado