# Comando ERRORLEVEL com cores?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd, cores

Criei um script `bat` para tesar alguns links, to usando o comando `ping` com o  `errorlevel` e tá funcionado perfeitamente, mas queria que quando eu não tivesse comunicação, ou seja, não pingasse, ele ficasse de outra cor, tipo vermelho. Se obter comunicação, ou seja, se pinga, ficar verde... alguém sabe algo que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Para cada solução que você tenta com um batch sobre o prompt de comandos do Windows ("cmd"), existe uma forma 10 vezes mais fácil de se fazer o mesmo com o PowerShell. Se não o conhece, dê uma olhada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41957/14584

Comment: Essa resposta aqui já fica nos meus favoritos, pq sempre me ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux

Comment: renato preciso para windows , alguma dica ?

Comment: Ola.

Este exemplo funciona: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7926476/1997073

Muito bom inclusive!

Comment: Veja se esta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213543/cmd-exe-batch-script-color-output-with-for-f-msys-commands) atende sua busca!

Answer (score 2):

Para comandos que rodem no Terminal do Linux a coisa parece ser bem mais fácil que no Prompt do Windows.

Esse *snippet* retirado [desse site](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting):

```
echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"
```

Faz com que um Hello World apareça escrito em vermelho.

Para o Prompt do Windows, vou deixar  [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344911/753531) do SOEN pois, pelo menos pra mim, são comandos muito complexos.

Eu achei a segunda menos confusa, mas ela deixa um arquivo temporário para trás, a aceita como melhor resposta não.

Se ja qual for sua escolha, a definição das cores a serem utilizadas é feito através de dois caracteres no argumento imediatamente após o termo precedido por um dois-pontos.

Para esse parâmetro cada um dos dois caracteres representam um hexadecimal da cor, sendo o primeiro caractere para a cor de *background* e o segundo para a de *foreground*.

E as cores não são lá muito variadas. [Nesse site](http://www.computerhope.com/color.htm) tem uma lista bem legível de opções válidas.

Espero que te ajude :)

Comment: O comando `Color` sugerido troca a cor de todo o terminal de texto, e não apenas da(s) próxima(s) linha(s) impressa(s). Então acho que não serve ao AP. A ideia de usar o `findstr` (no código enorme do SOEN citado) é bacana, mas além de complexa/feia usa algo externo. E nesse caso, já que se vai usar algo externo, talvez seja melhor mesmo o PowerShell (sugerido em um comentário) ou uma solução como essa: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17033/Add-Colors-to-Batch-Files